# how to check is in West or East beweet tow lang.log

Tags: flutter, dart

how to check is in West or East beweet tow lang.log

*how to check is in West or East beweet tow lang.log*

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.  Please include code in your explanation as there is no context in your question.

Comment: No code brother , just how to kwon the the location (lat long  ) is in the east  or west or north or south   in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know that the location is in east,west,north,south using lat long you simply need is a comparision.

You take reference latlong Can be the latlong user is currently.
You take the latlong of a point other than it and simply compare.

```
  double referenceLat = 40.7128;
  double referenceLng = -74.0060;

  double locationLat = 34.0522;
  double locationLng = -118.2437;

  String northSouth = locationLat > referenceLat ? 'North' : 'South';
  String eastWest = locationLng > referenceLng ? 'East' : 'West';

  print('The location is in the $northSouth and $eastWest of the reference point.');
```